# JS Error in WordPress WooCommerce: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using WooCommerce with Wordpress 3.8.3, we've suddenly lost our checkout buttons and add to cart buttons, and see this error in dev tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
```

It also gives the line of the index where the error occurs, but looking at index.php in dev tools is just blank. Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit* I was able to find the index content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() 
 {
    window.open(this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,'_self');
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the line of code. Its not possible to help you just showing the error.

Comment: Is there any element exist with `id="menu1"`?

Comment: No, no element called menu1 exists on the page

Comment: Are you able to edit your JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I can work directly in the theme files

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**conditional statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to the variable `urlmenu`.

Try this:

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );

if (urlmenu) {
    urlmenu.onchange = function() 
    {
        window.open(this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,'_self');
    };
}
```